# Access a namedtuple from subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am new to python and I am trying to use a namedTuple I have in my base class from my subclass however I am not having any luck

```
from collections import namedtuple 
class BaseExample(object):
    User = namedtuple('User', ['username', 'password'])
    job_employer_1 = User()
    job_employer_2 = User()
    job_seeker = User()

class Example(BaseExample):
    job_employer = User()
```

In my Example class I have an error for the User() which is as follows

```
Unresolved reference 'User'
```

How would I access it?

Comment: `BaseExample.User`

Comment: The issue is that the scope of the `User` class is defined under the `BaseExample` class, so only the code inside `BaseExample` can access it.  You can either define it outside of the class or use `BaseExample.User` to reference it in the `Example` class

Comment: Oh okay I thought the subclass would be able to see everything in the base class

Comment: Can you give it as an answer so I can give you credit